# Books and articles on Netty

Tags: java, netty

Are there some good articles/books about how to use Netty?
The documentation is short, and it's not simple for me to learn from the Javadoc.

Thanks

Comment: 'Netty in action' published this May
http://manning.com/maurer/

Comment: Suggest reading the < Netty in Action > v10 and practice with the Netty User Guide (https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/User-guide-for-4.x). But it may still not be an easy learning experience.

Answer (score 7):

Google is much greater then SO when you need to search!

[link](http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation)

**EDIT**:

[link from dzone1](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/netty_tutorial_part_1_introduction_to_netty.html)

[link from dzone2](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/netty_tutorial_part_15_on_channel_handlers_and_ch.html)

Comment: They moved their website (now it's http://netty.io) but as I said the documentation doesn't really explain how to rightly use the framework. It provides some basics and examples but I don't feel that I know how the framework works.

Comment: I'm afraid JBoss is well known for it's poor documentation. Look for articles of people, who have already used Netty. I've found some links on [DZone](http://dzone.com). See EDIT.

Comment: both the links mentioned have been recently written and are great for beginners for a good understanding !

Comment: both the links have been nuked

Answer (score 6):

I have found [this tutorial](http://seeallhearall.blogspot.gr/2012/05/netty-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to.html?m=1), which is mentioned in the [related articles](http://netty.io/wiki/related-articles.html) section of the main site useful.
Checking [the examples provided](http://netty.io/wiki/index.html) helps too.

Answer (score 4):

https://netty.io/Main/Related+Articles

Comment: I've already looked at this list, one tutorial explains very well the basics but I'm looking something more complete.

Comment: Hey Michael; I don't know if there is much else out there. I am sure the netty maintainers knew about anything else, they would have linked to it. Have you digested all the example code? Can you specify any detail on what you're looking for?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache After all, it's an open source project. If nothing else is out there, we still have the source code...